# Void callback subscriber does not work

Tags: ros, gazebo, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users

i would like to send odometry (just linear and angular velocity) to another IP via socket udp.

But I have a problem. The problem is that void velsubcallback is not executed and I do not why..
(The catkin_make is ok)

This is my .cpp and my int main (but i think we have to focus on while):

```
 void velsubcallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry& msg)
   {  
    variable1=msg.twist.twist.linear.x;
    variable2=msg.twist.twist.angular.z;
 lectura_ros.linear=variable1;
 lectura_ros.angular=variable2;
         ROS_INFO("variable %f",lectura_ros.linear);        
       }
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int va_send_to;
int long_dir_cli;
int socket_ros; 
struct sockaddr_in dir_serv_socket,dir_cli_socket;
  ros::init(argc, argv, "lanzando_vel");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
    while (ros::ok())
      {
    
      ros::Subscriber odom_sub = n.subscribe("p3dx/odom", 1000, velsubcallback);
      
    va_send_to = sendto(socket_ros,(char *)&lectura_ros,sizeof(dato_ros),0,(struct sockaddr *)&dir_cli_socket,sizeof(dir_cli_socket));
```

Any idea??

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208959/void-callback-subscriber-does-not-work/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-05-11**:
Have you checked, that data gets published on this topic?

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-05-11**:
First of all, thanks!

Yes, I have. Data is publishing on this topic but the problem is that void velsub callback is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Move your

```
  ros::Subscriber odom_sub = n.subscribe("p3dx/odom", 1000, velsubcallback);
```

outside the while loop. the subscriber only needs to be created once! And be sure to call `ros::spinOnce()` in your loop. This is the point code code where your callback are actually called!

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-05-12**:
Thank you so much. That is work!!